# Cannot save custom tag in new nav

Tags: bug, status-norepro, new-nav

Getting the following error while saving custom tab list:

[image: trying to save custom tab]

---

[image: getting error in the console]

Is any one facing the same issue or am I doing it in wrong way.

Comment: can you provide repro steps? Clearly saving work for most people, so it must be some other thing you do.

Comment: @Sklivvz working on new-nav is not consistent it worked for me later should i delete the question

Comment: @Sklivvz I'm getting the same thing here. My existing tab that was previously created always shows the `*` indicator and the save button is enabled. I also see the error on browser console.

Comment: @Sklivvz That error has now gone but when I save it seems OK until a refresh and the save button appears again. Also getting this new console error: `Uncaught TypeError: r.func_clear is not a function`